# How to set up local mail on AWS linux 2

Tags: linux, email, amazon-web-services, smtp

ISTR that in the old days, on most unix boxes you could just `mail` someone ... and it pretty much just worked. I have a pretty decent understanding of how mail servers work, but ... it turns out I don't have any recollection of how mail is supposed to work on a non-mail-server linux box, and it turns out that AWS Linux 2 comes with, AFAICT, no mail client installed.

What I want is for all of my servers running on my AWS VPC to be able to send mail both to users on the box, and via SMTP to my postfix server running on the LAN. I installed `mailx`, but if I try and send a mail to a local user, nothing gets there, and I get an entry in the logs that connection on port 25 was refused.

What do I need to configure and/or install to make this work? Running postfix on every server on the network seems insane, but ... maybe I'm wrong, maybe that's what's needed. But, I'm hoping I'm just missing a simple configuration, either at the OS level, or maybe for `mailx`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several implementations of `mail` and `mailx` (bsd-mailx, heirloom-mailx aka s-nail, GNU mailutils) and they have different requirements. All of them, however, support delivering mail through the `sendmail` program without depending on SMTP.

*(It is possible that older versions of 'mail' or 'mailx' supported direct delivery to other users' mail spools, e.g. through being setgid to the 'mail' group, but that doesn't seem to be a thing now.)*

Instead of Postfix, you could run the Exim4 mail software, whose 'sendmail' implementation will, by default, *immediately* perform the entire delivery in foreground (instead of just queuing the message like Postfix does) – if the recipient is remote it'll talk SMTP; for local ones it will directly write the message to their mbox.

This is a less secure design (a giant setuid binary attracts attention)
but it means Exim can send outgoing mail without a persistent daemon running (though, at minimum, you might want to run a hourly `exim -qf` cronjob to retry failed deliveries).

The Esmtp smarthost-only 'sendmail' tool also supports local delivery to /var/mail. (Though Esmtp is mostly unmaintained, and the most common replacement 'msmtp' only does smarthost-only delivery but not local mail.)

If you only wanted local mail, then you could of course write your own implementation of 'sendmail' that does nothing more except local delivery – all it needs is to accept the message via stdin and the recipients (plus some options) via argv.